# How to fix a Joomla plugin manifest?

Tags: xml, joomla, joomla-extensions

I've developed a simple plugin for Joomla! 3.6 but I can't get it installed on my server. I tried different setup methods and after some researchs I think that the problem resides inside my XML manifest.

The error I get is:

```
Attention: JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file
Error: Cannot find installation package
```

My XML manifest is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.6" type="plugin" group="mygroup" method="upgrade">
<name>plg_mygroup_emailnotify</name>
<author>Frollo</author>
<creationDate>2017-01-25</creationDate>
<copyright>Copyright (C) 2017 Frollo</copyright>
<license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt</license>
<authorEmail></authorEmail>
<authorUrl></authorUrl>
<version>1.0.1</version>
<description>PLG_MYGROUP_EMAILNOTIFY_XML_DESCRIPTION</description>

<files>
    <filename plugin="emailnotify">emailnotify.php</filename>
    <folder>language</folder>
</files>

<config>
    <fields name="params">

        <fieldset name="PLG_FIELDSET_GENERAL">
          <field name="general_mailfrom_address"
                 type="email"
                 label="PLG_GENERAL_MAILFROM_ADDRESS"
                 description="PLG_GENERAL_MAILFROM_ADDRESS_DESC"
            />

            <field name="general_mailfrom_name"
                   type="text"
                   default=""
                   label="PLG_GENERAL_MAILFROM_NAME"
                   description="PLG_GENERAL_MAILFROM_NAME_DESC"
                   size="30" />

        </fieldset>
        <fieldset name="PLG_EMAILNOTIFY_FIELDSET_ESTIMATE">
          <field
            name="estimate_approve_link"
            type="text"
            default="http://wwww.example.com"
            />
        </fieldset>

    </fields>
</config>
</extension>
```

EDIT - Some other details:
I have had no troubles installing other plugins or components on the server. The directory structure is the following:

```
+ emailnotify
  + language
    + it-IT
      - it-IT.ini
  - emailnotify.php
  - emailnotify.xml
```

Comment: Your xml file might be fine. Maybe it is the zip file which is invalid. Can you add information about all the files you put to this zip file? Can you install other packages in this server?

Comment: I updated the question, adding more informations

Comment: I created a install package with the structure you mentioned and the xml content. It installed without any issue. How does your install package looks like? Can you install it on another server? Does this package works for you? https://www.svenbluege.de/downloads/emailnotify.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the last fieldset. The default url contained some GET parameters, in the form

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?param1=param1&param2=param2
```

The presence of the `&` broke the XML, replacing it with `&amp;` fixed the XML

Answer (score 0):

Your xml manifest file have unclosed `<extension>` root node.

Comment: I copied it wrong, the closing tag is present inside the file. I'm fixing the question.